# HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext always returns null on Product Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

VS2017, .net core 2.0, webapi, autofac

I need to use HttpContext in my service and pass an http header as a token to identify the user, resulted as a SessionContext object to be injected.

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(context => context.Resolve<LoginService>().GetSession(context.Resolve<HttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Request.Headers));
```

and other services are registed like this

```
//Other services
{
    IRegistrationBuilder<object, Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle> MassiveRegister<T>() => builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).InNamespace(baseNamespace + ".Services").AssignableTo<T>().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition && !t.IsAbstract).PreserveExistingDefaults().OnActivated(e => ((IService)e.Instance).Initialize()).OnActivating(e => e.Context.AutoInjectAll(e.Instance));
    MassiveRegister<ISessionalService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    MassiveRegister<IService>().SingleInstance();
}
```

When normally executed or debugged with Visual Studio, it works perfectly,
but when the program is published (on both IIS or self-host) and executed out of Visual Studio, `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` always returns null when `SessionContext` is required by other services (as a property injected by calling `InjectUnsetProperties` as follows).

```
//Called by Startup
public static class AutoDIExtensions
{
    public static void AutoInjectAll(this IComponentContext context, object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            context.InjectUnsetProperties(obj);
        }
        catch (DependencyResolutionException ex) when (ex.InnerException.UnpackThrough() is ActionException)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried many ways like changing the lifescope of the services, changing build configs... but they seem not helping at all.

So is it really a framework bug or I need a correct way to access `HttpContext`?

Comment: The AspNetCore resolves `IHttpContextAccessor`, not `HttpContextAccessor`. Or does autofac automatically resolve all the interfaces?

Comment: Ah thats the point, I tried to change the registering code to 
 `builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(context => context.Resolve<LoginService>().GetSession(context.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Request.Headers));` and the problem was solved, so the point is, the AspNetCore actively stores the `HttpContext` into the solved singleton `IHttpContextAccessor`, so registering `HttpContextAccessor` cannot be resolved by AspNetCore, and what I thought was it was HttpContextAccessor who gets the HttpContext @Tratcher

Comment: But the weird one is, registering HttpContextAccessor still works on Development Environment, but how comes? @Tratcher

Comment: Maybe something is conditionally registering it for you in dev.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793